# Can we make read-only mode text more visible?

Tags: feature-request, design

Today it seemed many (possibly all) of the stack exchange sites were put into a read only mode.  I first noticed this on stackoverflow

[image: Stackoverflow message]

and the message definitely caught my attention.  Thinking that it might only be for SO I decided to come here and check some stuff out.

[image: Much harder to notice]

The same thing was happening here. However, I didn't notice this for a while.  Could we possibly make the message more visible so that users can much more easily tell that the site is in read only mode?  SO has a yellow banner that catches the eye.  The message here just sort of blends in and doesn't really even seem like an announcement.

EDIT: I didn't really lose any time today but it did take me a few seconds to realize what was going on.  Once again I don't think the read-one mode notification is noticeable enough.  Can we please do something to make it stand out more?

Comment: Having lost ~1 hour of work on a question I was typing up on SO due to that outage (became too reliant on SO auto-saving feature), I am greatly surprised that people wouldn't notice that they weren't logged in.

Comment: The more general request here is to make the system message bar more noticeable. (The read-only notice is just one example of a system message.) I agree that it's pretty well hidden right now. Still. This sure has been an issue for a while. :)